# T list should take multiple values

Tags: c#, list

I want to populate a list with user input specifying a `start` period and an `end` period. The answer goes into a loan calculation, which has the possibility of periods of non-repayment. The list should offer the possibility of an unspecified number of `start` and `end` sequences (specified by user input).

I am trying to get the T-list to accept `start` and `end` sequences under the same index number, like so:

```
List<int> NonRepymnt = new List<int>();
NonRepymnt.Add(2, 4);
```

but I get an error. I am unsure whether this means that the T-list doesn't accept multiple values or I just don't get the syntax right. I have been looking in the documention under 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx
which seems to offer the possibility of multiple entries, but it doesn't work for me. Help appreciated, thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your list is of type `int` so it should get only `int` items. Here you are trying to add a different type: a complex type with "begin" and "end".

1. One way is to use Named Tuples if using C# 7.0:

   ```
   var list = new List<(int begin, int end)>();    
   list.Add((0, 10));
   ```

   If prior to C# 7.0 you can use "normal" tuples:

   ```
   var list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
   list.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(0, 10));
   ```
2. Another option is to create a custom class:

   ```
   class Period
   {
       public int Begin { get; set; }
       public int End{ get; set; }
   }

   var list = new List<Period>();
   list.Add(new Period { Begin = 0, End = 10 });
   ```

---

If I misunderstood and you just want a simple `List<int>` and populate it with multiple values at once then use `AddRange`:

```
list.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there are named tuples in c#7. I really hated the `Item1`...`Itemn`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled - ya..... The main reason not to use tuples before that in my mind :) Having to "remember" what each `ItemX` means.... Great they added it. Makes it a bit more python-like in this aspect :)

Comment: @Gilad. Thanks for the insight. I am looking for int values (ie. 2,4) not "begin" and "end", they were just for illustrating that I am looking into a time span. I have seen other posts on SO that warns against the use of tuples, but i think the AddRange will do it. I just didn't find it in my reference material or on SO (why whas I downvoted?? It's not a duplicate as far as I can see)

Comment: @Gilad: Btw what do you mean by simple list? The list needs to be exandable, so based on user input there can be several time spans in the list, where the number of time spans will be unknown at runtime.   I understand that CS v. 7.0 operates better w Tuples. I'll look into that. Thx!

Comment: @Aurelius - if I understand correctly pairs of items in the list have a meaning right? If I have `1 2 3 4` - then `1 2` are a pair which each have a meaning and then same for `3 4`... is that correct?

Comment: @Aurelius - BTW downvotes are probably because you didn't show what you have tried

Comment: @Gilad. Yes correct. The pairs would indicate a period which could for instance mean payment term 8 spanning to payment terrm 12, where "term" could mean month, quarter or year.

Comment: @Aurelius - so in that case it is better to have a class with two fields for that, beginning and end, and have a list of that class, rather than just a `List<int>` - just as in answer above :)